# Magento Wordpress integration or standalone for KB & FAQ? Please advise

Tags: magento-1.9, wordpress

I am thinking of either integrating Wordpress to my most current Magento .com website installation or using a .help domain extension of my website which I can install WordPress to and add a knowledge base to it for articles which contain information in regards to my main .com Magento site.

If the latter then when users visit my main Magento .com website and click on Knowledge base or FAQ link(s) for example then they will be redirected to my .help Wordpress site where articles with information will be presented for my main .com website. Will this work and is it advisable? Or should I integrate Wordpress to my Magento installation by finding readily available extensions and installing them?

Which is the better option in your opinion?

Appreciate and thanking you in advance for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of security: Seperate Magento and Wordpress as much as you can. More: Seperate your Magento online shop from any other CMS (seperate DB, seperate vhost, server,...).

Wordpress is quite vulnerable and once someone breaks your Worpdress installation, they will easily be able to acces your shop otherwise.

Comment: Hi Anna, thanks for the insight. I will be installing wordpress on another domain on the same server and same host due to the fact I need users to have created a new account on magento which will then create an account in wordpress for them too

Answer (score 0):

Like you said you can either opt to integrate WordPress by using e.g. Fishpig or use one of the existing knowledge base extensions, as well. Furthermore, you could also create a different store-view for your KB using a sub-domain.

It depends if you want to share content too, e.g. integrate static blocks into specific pages which might favor existing KB extensions.

Either way, most of the times I decide to integrate WordPress for these scenarios since setup and management is easy.

Comment: Would it not be better or will it be any different in terms of resource load and system performance if I decide to use WordPress by integrating it to Magento instead of using it separately on an addon domain and redirect my customers or/and visitors to my FAQ and KB site through a link located in my main .com website?

Comment: By addon domain you mean store view domain? Requests to WordPress integrated into Magento through e.g. Fishpig should be tunneled "pretty" efficiently to WordPress directly. Make sure to use separate databases for Magento and WordPress to reduce database load. If you are having such a high load you might want to consider to setup WordPress on a separate server instance as well.

Comment: An addon domain such as mydomain.help for example to my main mydomain.com site, install WP to mydomain.help and redirect visitors and customers to, through mydomain.com links for tutorials, knowledge base articles and FAQ's instead of integrating WordPress to my current installation which will add more strain to my site as a whole. Is this a good idea or should I steer clear and integrate anyway? I don't need to use blocks etc through Magento as all the content will be more tutorial based for my potential customers and visitors which will help navigating around my main mydomain.com website.

Comment: Alright, then it's better to separate these two systems as you can tune them independently.